# Check if number in string with regex

Tags: regex

My regex knowledge is strictly limited, but I need to use it to check a string for a specific number, e.g.

```
12345 123543 123222 4124214 2323 42124 23123 24444 34342
```

How can I use regex to confirm whether `2323` is in the above string?

Basically, if the string contains the number, for my project, then the string and the number are a match. If this isn't clear, please let me know and I'll try to expand.

Comment: Does it have to match a full number? For example, is `4444` in your example string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex for checking if `2323` is in the string is:

```
.*\b2323\b.*
```

This means anything, then `2323`, then anything. The `\b`s will make sure that the `2323` is not in the middle of a number, but its own number. (Without the `\b` word boundaries, the regex would match `83523238` because it has `2323` in it.)

Comment: That's great, thank you very much, will it ensure that spaces are used to separate numbers in the string? As I can't allow 2323 to match 152323 etc

Comment: @JeremyHewitt That's why the `\b`s are there